# Limit number of words user enters into a text box without button click action

Tags: javascript

I want to limit number of words that user input to a text box . I tried one code  it was successfull for only single text box when i ammend it to multiple text box this code did not work, An advice will be really appreciated.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    x=document.myForm
    input=x.myInput.value
    if (input.length>5){
        alert("The field cannot contain more than 5 characters!")
        return false
    }else {
        return true
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="http://www.java2s.com" onsubmit="return validate()">
Enter some text (less than 5 characters):
<input type="text" name="myInput" size="20">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please note, there is a difference between `Words` and `Characters`

Comment: Is your query resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the maxlength attribute or trim the string everytime the user enters into it. Using maxlength is a better way of doing it

```js
var input = document.getElementById("limit5");
var LIMIT = 5;
input.onkeyup=function(){
  if(input.value.length > LIMIT){
    input.value = input.value.substr(0,LIMIT);
    //alert("Please limit your input to 5 characters")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="autolimit5" maxlength="5" type="text"/>
<input id="limit5" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Thank you chirag..I tried tmaxlength method also,,but my project supervisor said that is not user friendly. He ask me to show an error message when word limit exceeds

Comment: In that case, you can trigger your alert inside the if condition too. Have updated code to illustrate

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to go about it:

**Method 1:**
Using the `maxlength="5"` attribute

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="5" name="somename"/>
```

**Method 2:**

Using Javascript:

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitInput(field, max) {
    if (field.value.length > max) {
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, max);
    }
}
</script>

    <input type="text" name="somename" onKeyDown="limitInput(this,5);" onKeyUp="limitInput(this,5);"" />
```

**UPDATE**

With a message:

```html
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var errHolder = document.getElementById('err');
    function limitInput(field, max) {
        if (field.value.length > max) {
          err.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
        else
        {
          err.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    </script>

        <span>
        <input type="text" name="somename" onKeyDown="limitInput(this,5);" onKeyUp="limitInput(this,5);" />
</span>
<span id="err" style="display:none;background-color:red;">Please enter less than 5 characters</span>
```

Comment: Instead of `onKeyDown="limitInput(this,5);"`, its better to use `.addEventListener`

Comment: @Rajesh I agree that it is also an approach to validate the length. But I don't see how and why that is a better approach, please elaborate..

Comment: Thanks Shakthi, I tried this maxlength method also. But my supervisor said it is not user friendly. He ask me to show  an error message when user exceeds the word limit

Comment: @sad Sure you can do that.. let me update the answer for you

Comment: Really nice shakthi,,,Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to to prevent user from entering data in form elements. What you are trying is to validate all data in one go when user clicks on the Submit button. It would be better to validate at the time when the user is typing. Basically there are 4 related events whenever the user presses anything on the keyboard.

1. onKeyPress
2. onKeyDown
3. onKeyUp
4. onInput

You can use a combination of these events to achieve anything that you want. For the use case in the question we can just use keypress event.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    x=document.myForm
    input=x.myInput.value
    if (input.length>5){
        alert("The field cannot contain more than 5 characters!")
        return false
    }else {
        return true
    }
}

// function which runs on every keypress of input element to which this 
// function is attached
function validateTextField(e){
    if(event.currentTarget.value.length >= 5){ 
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="http://nothing.com" onsubmit="return validate()">
Enter some text (less than 5 characters):
<input type="text" name="myInput" size="20" onkeypress="return validateTextField(event)">
<input type="text" name="anotherInput" size="20" onkeypress="return validateTextField(event)">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>enter code here
```

If you want, you can customize the size for the validation by changing some of the parameters

Update the html input definition with below

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" size="20" onkeypress="return validateTextField(event, 5)">
<input type="text" name="anotherInput" size="20" onkeypress="return validateTextField(event, 8)">
```

Update the function definition to use the second parameter

```
function validateTextField(e, size){
    console.log(e);
    if(event.currentTarget.value.length >= size){ 
        return false;
    }
}
```